# Somebody explain the space in assignments in shell scrpting - Obvious but what is the reason?

Tags: bash, shell, hdfs

I am trying to understand the following

```
$ HDFS_FILE = 'hdfs:///user/svcid/project/app/sample.txt'

-ksh: HDFS_FILE: not found [No such file or directory]
```

But whenI remove space between

> HDFS_FILE< >=< >'hdfs:///user/svcid/project/app/sample.txt'

then it works fine.

```
$ HDFS_FILE='hdfs:///user/svcid/project/app/sample.txt'


$ echo $HDFS_FILE

hdfs:///user/svcid/project/app/sample.txt
```

Why does it behave like that?

Comment: Spaces are used to separate a command from its arguments. If you put a space there, it thinks `HDFS_FILE` is the name of the command to run, and `=` is the first argument.

Comment: Assignments can't have any whitespace around the `=`.